# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'

Tags: bash, escaping

I get this error **bash** on my virtual hosting, in cron tasks. My command is following:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --user=USERNAME --password="C\(mRA0_ifmv\(" DATABASE > ROOTFOLDER/backup/$(date +%F).sql && gzip ROOTFOLDER/backup/$(date +%F).sql
```

I hid real *user*, *database* and *home folder* for security purposes. So, I understand that my password causes this error, but I don't want to change it.

How can I escape open bracket char or avoid this error and why "\" doesn't work?

Comment: From `man mysqldump`: __Specifying a password on the command line should be considered insecure.__ See Section 6.1.2.1, “End-User Guidelines for Password Security”. You can use an option file to avoid giving the password on the command line.

Comment: Concur. Your problem here is that you're using `--password=` in the first place. Use an ini file instead and the entire issue goes away AND becomes more secure.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes for the password.

```
--password='C\(mRA0_ifmv\('
```

> [Bash Manual: Single Quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html)
>
> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal
> value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not
> occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> [Bash Manual: Double Quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html)
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal
> value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’,
> ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’.

Comment: Since "\" is not a part of password, thne I need to remove backslashes, right?

Comment: That is correct.  Did it work?

Comment: No, "unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'". But I forgot to add that this is not a real bash, it's jailshell from cPanel distributive.